# Require valid-user except for one specific image

Tags: .htaccess

I use `.htaccess` with `.htpasswd`
But I would like to exclude a single file

So I tried it but it does not work

```
AuthName "No"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "C:\wamp\www\blabla\.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
<FilesMatch public/images/logo.png>
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetEnvIfNoCase` like this to allow a certain URI or URIs to skip auth:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "/public/images/logo\.png$" NO_AUTH

AuthName "No"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "C:\wamp\www\blabla\.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
```